# How to combine an aggregate SQL query and normal query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, aggregate

I have a table in SQL 2005 that I want to aggregate data from, here is an example.

```
JobName       ProductionCounter       StartDate             EndDate               CounterName        Stage
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

200           23                      2012-08-30 13:45:00                          Kilograms          Final
200           2                       2012-08-30 13:45:00                          Bars               Final
    [...]
200           46                      2012-08-30 13:45:00   2012-08-30 17:23:00    Kilograms          Final
200           4                       2012-08-30 13:45:00   2012-08-30 17:23:00    Bars               Final
300           20                      2012-08-30 13:45:00                          Kilograms          1st
300           10                      2012-08-30 18:12:00                          Bars               1st
    [...]
300           40                      2012-08-30 18:12:00   2012-08-30 19:17:00    Kilograms          1st
300           20                      2012-08-30 18:12:00   2012-08-30 19:17:00    Bars               1st

I want to format this into the following


JobName      TotalKilos       TotalBars       StartDate             EndDate               Stage
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

200          69               6               2012-08-30 13:45:00   2012-08-30 17:23:00   Final
300          60               30              2012-08-30 18:12:00   2012-08-30 19:17:00   1st
```

This has made me realise I know nothing about SQL.  I have tried the following as a start

```
SELECT JobName, SUM(KiloCounter)
FROM vwOeeInterval
GROUP BY JobName

SELECT JobName, SUM(BarCounter)
FROM vwOeeInterval
GROUP BY JobName
```

My questions are:

1. How do I combine these into one query?
2. How would I query for the columns such as StartDate and Stage?  Especially where the End Date
   is not filled in until the job completes?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple aggregation query.  You just need to add the fields that you want:

```
SELECT JobName, SUM(KiloCounter) as TotalKilos,
       sum(BarCounts) as TotalBars,
       min(StartDate) as StartDate,
       max(EndDate) as EndDate,
       max(Stage) as Stage 
FROM vwOeeInterval
GROUP BY JobName
```

I am presuming that you know that StartDate, EndDate, and Stage are the same or NULL for all rows with the same job.  The aggregation will ignore the NULL values.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I have made progress using max() and min() but I have realised I have not explained myself correctly.  I want to query the ProductionCounter WHERE the CounterName is "Kilos" and have this 'AS' a column 'KiloCounter'.

I also want to query where the CounterName is 'Bars', but I am figuring this would need to be two separate SELECTs joined somehow?

Comment: @TimRees . . . The best thing to do in this situation is to ask another question, providing before and after data as you did.  If you just modify your question, people will read it, see the answers already posted, and wonder why these answers are so off-base.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to get the sum based on the **Jobname** first and then the **countername**, you should be grouping based on those 2 columns.

**Do NOT forget to select the two columns that you are grouping by**

A sample would look something like this - 
`Select column1, column2, sum(column3) from tablename`  
`where blah blah blah...`
`group by column1, column2`